# Date Pick Day Month Year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

but the only thing i can see is fetch an alert of the whole time day month

```
$(function() {
    $('#popupDatepicker').datepick();
    $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({onSelect: showDate});
});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
```

i want to know how do i make them split up to like

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="popupDatepicker"> When i select date here the fields in the hidden will change below
<input type="hidden" name="day">
<input type="hidden" name="month">
<input type="hidden" name="year">
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the date picker's `onselect` handler is that passes the date as a string using whatever format you've put onto the date picker.

You can use `$('#inlineDatepicker').datepicker('getDate')` to get an actual `Date` object representing the selected date.

You can also use [`$.datepicker.formatDate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) to convert that object into alternative string formats, or use the `Date` object's own methods to extract the numeric values.